# Linq to sql submit changes () or .Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, "entity to update")

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, datacontext

Hello guys as you can see on my Title, I am wondering what is more safe and more stable to use when we are talkin about **Linq to SQL**, SubmitChanges() method or
.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, "entity to update"), because obliviosly we need to use them everytime we are making changes on database table, thats true?

Because in case we are not using them, we will never had updated database model in our IDE (for example visual studio).

I just started working with linq to sql and I WANT TO understand both helpers, why should I or why should not I use any of them.

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods do incomparable things. `SubmitChanges` writes to the database and `Refresh` reads from the database.

`Refresh` is pretty much never needed because normally you are making all writes through entities. This means that the entities are always up to date.

Comment: but what about this mate: I update field in database like Status i.e I set it to false, and immediatly after that I'm calling method to give me all rows where Status is set to true, if I don't call `.Refresh` after I update my database table I will still gettin UN UPDATED row?

Comment: You should update using the ORM. Then, there is no syncing issue. If you update without L2S knowing then you have a sync issue, yes. That's a really rare case because it is really bad practice. In fact, the sync issue is non-deterministic. If the entity is new, it's fresh. If it existed before the query, it's old. So don't do that :)

Comment: so mate can you give me example of good practice, because that's how I learned to use it : do some table change, call refresh method and keep going, so can you please provide me link or write one example how that should look, me and I guess a lot users wordwide would be very thankful about that!! :)

Comment: I already told you: Make changes to your entities, call SubmitChanges. Why can't you do that?

Comment: Acctualy I can, so it would work like this, make some changes, example insert and delelte, I have to call Insert/delete on submit method and pass entity object and call `SubmitChanges()` method. Thanks mate, I will try than rather than calling `.Refresh` after single insert/update to my database...

Comment: It's really easy... If you find yourself refreshing or attaching or doing other funky things it's a code smell. This is not how L2S is meant to be used. It's meant to give you objects that act as if the whole database was in memory as normal objects.

Comment: great mate, I will keep working like that, guy who used to teach us how stuffs works told us acctualy to do that, insert - > refresh, update -> refresh, and that's reason why I wrote this question because I believed there is another answer/better solution, and thank you a lot on your time to answer me on a right way!