# c# linq to sql - updating database table

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, linq

I'm wondering is this a bad concept of usage linq to sql to update item in my database, what I am doing is: I'm changing status of my selected item (talking about orders) from 0 to 1 and it looks like this (current code):

Method I'm calling to **set/change** my item status:

```
OrdersController.SetOrderStatusTrue(orderNumber);
```

Method's code:

```
public static void SetOrderStatusTrue(int numberOforder)
{
    DataServices.DB.procedure_SetOrderStatus_ToTrue(numberOforder); //procedure which will set status to "1".
    DataServices.DB.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,DataServices.DB.Orders.Where(nmbr => nmbr.OrderNumber == numberOforder));            //is this a bad concept to call refresh ?
}
```

So I'm wondering is this bad concept to call `Refresh` Method every time I'm changing my item status, Maybe I should somehow apply `SubmitChanges` method,
could anyone tell me which concept is better, this concept also work, but I read on few posts that is not good practice to call refresh like this every time, so is that true and how should it look with `SubmitChanges` method?

Cheers

Comment: This makes me suspect that DataServices.DB` is (or contains0 a long-lived datacontext. *That* is the bad practice here. If you use short-lived contexts you wouldn't need Refresh.

Comment: @Gert Arnold How could I use short-lived contexts and what is that?

Comment: Create context, use it (to read data, save data, whatever), dispose it. Typically, you would use contexts in `using` statements.

Comment: @GertArnold I'll join this post I had same problems, so after I read your comment I think with your suggestion that this might look like this, correct me if I'm wrong: `public static void SetOrderStatusTrue(int numberOforder)
{
 using(SampleDataContext dbContext = new SampleDataContext())
 {
  dbContext.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.OrderID==numberOforder)
  dbContext.Orders.Status=true;
  dbContext.SubmitChanges();
 }
}` And what if there are 10 orders with same numberOfOrder how could update happen to all of them? somehow get list with same `numberOfOrder?`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at this post: [Linq to sql submit changes () or .Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, "entity to update")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831093/linq-to-sql-submit-changes-or-refreshsystem-data-linq-refreshmode-overwrite)

Basically whats being said there is : Refresh is pretty much never needed because normally you are making all writes through entities. This means that the entities are always up to date.

Hopefully this anwers your question.

Comment: and how that should look if I won't use .Refresh method, lets say I want to solve this by using SubmitChanges method, how that acctualy might look in this case